# Find the length of a ladder that is leaning against a wall.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A ladder leans against a wall at a point $8$ feet above the ground. The bottom of the ladder rests $2$ feet away from the wall. How long is the ladder?

Comment: Use pythagorus theorem and compute $l = \sqrt{(8^2+2^2)}$

Answer (score 1):

Use Pythagorean Theorem: $a^2 + b^2=c^2$

Let $a=2$, $b=8$ and $c$ be the length of the ladder.  Plug in your values and solve for C.

Answer (score 0):

From what I believe is the question this is just an easy application of the Pythagoras theorem

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

Where $c$ is the longest side and $b$ and $a$ are the other sides.  So in your question, we know that $a=2$ and $b=8$ so we need to solve for $c$.  We can plug the numbers in to get the answer

$2^2+8^2=c^2=68$  so $c=\sqrt{68}$ feet I believe

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\theta = 8/2=4\implies \theta=\tan^{-1}4$$

Note that
$$\sec\theta = h/2$$
$$2\sec\theta = h$$
$$h=2\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}=2\sqrt{\tan^2(\tan^{-1}4)+1}=2\sqrt{4^2+1}=2\sqrt{17}$$